# SqliteNetExtensions is it possible to ignore a specified child when calling InsertOrReplaceWithChildren()?

Tags: c#, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm building a mobile app in xamarin that has a lot of relationships between classes. For simplicity consider it to be a "University" app that has the classes: ExamPapers, Students, ExamAnswers.

The ExamPaper class would look like this

```
public class ExamPapers {
    [ManyToMany(typeof(Student_ExamPaper))]
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<ExamAnswers> Files { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<ExamSection> Sections { get; set; }

    public string ExamName { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

So at the moment any sqlitenetextension operation (the ones that end with "WithChildren") will interact with all the relationships when I often just want to interact with one at a time. Here are some example scenarios:

1. A student "Lana" is just granted access to an ExamPaper "Mathematics 101". Now to grant her access I need to load; all other students with access, all the files for the exam, all the sections. Otherwise these relationships get deleted when I call "InsertOrReplaceWithChildren".
2. I want to find out the first question in an ExamPaper. I call "GetWithChildren(examId)". I now have an object with a lot of information I don't want (e.g. 300 students and 300 ExamAnswers).

Sorry if I missed something relevant in the documentation, but I've read it through a couple times now. https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on your question in title: **No. You cannot.**
SQLite-Net-Extensions does not provide such flexible API for manipulating related data.

But there is one helpful thing that can be used in *specific cases*:

You can work with junction tables as simple tables through SQLite-Net methods (methods without `*WithChildren` postfix) if junction tables has PrimaryKey (`Id`).
For example if you have any data which you want to get withoud additional (related) data, just simply call `Table</*class*/>()` method on specific table with `Where(/*your condition*/)` clause for getting only data that you really need. Then you can save modified data through `Update` method.

Unfortunately, this thing will not work with relations **update** (for example, if you want to move one `ExamAnswer` from `ExamPaper` to another `ExamPaper` object) because all SQLite-Net-Extensions attributes inherited from `Ignore` SQLite-Net attribute which is ignoring in all SQLite-Net operations.
But there is another one workaround (a little hacky), you can specify second class without any SQLite-Net-Extensions attributes and that's provide you to CRUD any field in specific table.